# (Swift) Transferring Data between View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to transfer a value between my view controllers. When I simply connect my button to the other view controller, like this:

[image]

I am able to make it work. I am overriding `prepareforSegue`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DestinationViewController : ViewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewTwo
    DestinationViewController.scoretext = score.text!
}
```

It all works fine but when I open the other controller programatically, the value isn't transferred. This is the code I'm using for that...

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc : ViewTwo = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewtwo") as! ViewTwo
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, `prepareForSegue` is not called. You will have to assign scoretext after instantiation only.

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc : ViewTwo = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewtwo") as! ViewTwo
vc.scoretext = score.text!
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it !